# Right way to access private data from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to understand what is the right architecture to use to access data from servers hosted on a private network (still running on Azure but not publicly accessible) and the Azure Data Factory service.

On some documentation Microsoft mentions the Integration Runtime as the solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime

While on other documentation it refers to a Data Gateway:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway

Both articles seem fairly recent. The two applications have different recommended requirements (one mentions 8 CPU cores! Which is an overkill for my requirements to ship a few hundred megabytes per night)

Given that the data sources are running on Azure, just not publicly accessible, is there a way to connect Azure Data Factory directly?

Answer (score 1):

The Self Hosted Integration Runtime in ADF should meet your requirement, this [link](https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2018/07/03/how-to-get-azure-data-factory-connecting-to-your-data-on-a-vnet-or-internal-network/) gives a complete example to access data under Azure VNet or private network.